# Flutter Dropdown Container/Widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have spent hours googling something that should be incredibly simple, but have found nothing to this sort on the internet. Effectively, I want to make a dropdown, so that when a button is clicked, I have a menu dropdown. **However**, I **do not** wish to have this dropdown be a list of items. I want the dropdown to be able to take in a child widget, similar to the showDialog function, and I can pass what I wish to the child widget.

Eg., I wish to merge dropdown's positioning with dialog ability to not only render an opinionated list.

Does anyone have any clue how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [flutter_portal](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_portal). I used this package to build many types of dropdowns.
[image]

Comment: issue with this is for switching between web and mobile the library doesn't really support the different views

Answer (score 0):

Another way I found to do this is to use the showGeneralDialog function and customize the position.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to copy the implementation of [`PopupMenuDivider`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/PopupMenuDivider-class.html):

```dart
class MyEntry extends PopupMenuEntry<Never> {
  const MyEntry();
  
  @override
  double get height => kMinInteractiveDimension;

  @override
  bool represents(void value) => false;

  @override
  State<MyEntry> createState() => _MyEntryState();
}

class _MyEntryState extends State<MyEntry> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MyWidget();
  }
```

And then you can use it in a `PopupMenuButton`:

```dart
class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyButton();
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PopupMenuButton(
      itemBuilder: (context) {
        return [
          const MyEntry();
        ];
      },
      onSeleted: (_) {},
      child: MyChild(),
    );
  }
}
```