# How to create dropdown widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdown

I am trying to make a dropdown widget that appears from the location of the clicked widget. I know there are a lot of solutions on the internet already regarding this, however, none of the ones I found serve my specific needs.

1. Using dropdown packages: This does not work, as these widgets do not provide any way of customization. They are always just lists of items. What I want is a dropdown Container that I can fully customize.
2. Using dialogs: It is tough to customize the location of these dialogs. I want it to appear right at the location of the clicked button/widget.

[The white circle here is the widget that is supposed to be clicked on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnE6v.jpg)

[This is what is supposed to appear after clicking the circle. As you can see here it is not placed correctly. The circle in the widget and the circle we click should be on top of each other. And the dropdown itself should be a container not a list of widgets like here as opposed to a dropdown list.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5RKJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71400178/flutter-dropdown-container-widget) should provide you with an answer. 
If not, feel free to say so. 
(The answer points to this package: [flutter_portal](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_portal))

Comment: You need to add some code over here rather than just writing link as that link can be deleted in future.